# How to show a badge count on the custom viewsContainers icon in my vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my vscode extension, I want to show a badge count on the viewsContainers icon, just like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71972965/836330 for a demo and code on using badges on `ViewContainers` , vscode v1.72 Insiders for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be part of VSCode 1.72 (Sept. 2022), since [issue 62783](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/62783) was implemented with [PR 159679](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/159679/files).

It is available today in [VSCode insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

> ### badges on custom activities added to activity bar by extensions
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22587994/40053697-997c15dc-5842-11e8-87b0-444531094fa1.png]
>
> It would come helpful if extensions which create new activity in activity bar could also display a badge with a count. For example [`Gruntfuggly/todo-tree`#22](https://github.com/Gruntfuggly/todo-tree/issues/22) has request to show number of `TODO`/`FIXME` found in the project.

---

Note: with [PR 157462](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157462), you will also be able to hide search result decoration:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31675041/188728202-2477dbdc-9c50-47cb-abbd-fdc44f86c419.gif]

- `search.decorations.colors`: Controls whether search file decorations should use colors.
- `search.decorations.badges`: Controls whether search file decorations should use badges.